# Upload data from AWS S3 to RDS MySQL

Tags: amazon-web-services

Situation: Several customers send their inventory data daily via CSV files and these files are being stored on AWS S3.

Question: How do I send data from these CSV files to a MySQL RDS database every time a customer sends a file?

Note: the files are already structured, so what I would have to do would be something I know like BULK INSERT for MSSQL or LOAD DATA INFILE for MySQL.

Currently the only solution I am finding is the AWS DataPipeline for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Lambda that gets triggered when a new file is added to the S3, connect to the database and push the info.

You should create an IAM role that has access to the particular RDS and assign it to the lambda.

Comment: But you can't call the MySQL " LOAD DATA " statement from Lambda or dynamic SQL.  it has a lot of limitations.  Would be good to have an alternate way to move data from S3 to Arora MySQL directly.  A hack would be to read the file data into the lambda and then have the lambda do some kind of instert into MySQL but this creates a lot more exposure to failure.